# How to get user name from the table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables one keeps the log and the other one keeps the user name.

Table one(logs) has

```
ID|USERID|DATETIME|MESSAGE
```

Table two(users) has

```
ID|USERNAME|PASSWORD
```

In codeigniter model I have

```
    function getRlog(){

    $this->db->limit(100);
    $this->db->order_by("id","desc");
    $this->db->where('type', "reservation");
    $q = $this->db->get('logs');
        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($q->result() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    return $data;
   }

}
```

In the controller I have...

```
    function log(){
        if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You must be an admin to view this page');
        redirect('auth/login');
        } else {
        $data ['user'] = $this->ion_auth->get_user();
        $this->load->model('Logs_model');
        $data['logs'] = $this->Logs_model->getRlog();
        $this->load->view('database/log', $data);

        }
}
```

I want to get the **username** from the **users** table based on the **id** from the logs table. Should I create a foreign key? and If I do how do I get the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might do it this way in your model

```
function getRlog(){

    $this->db->limit(100);
    $this->db->order_by("id","desc");
    $this->db->where('type', "reservation");
    $q = $this->db->get('logs');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = array();  //create new data array to be returned
        foreach($q->result() as $row){
            $row->user = $this->ion_auth->get_user($row->userid);  //create new user property that contains user object
            $data[] = $row;  //append to new data array with appended user property
        }
        return $data;
    }
    else {
        return false; //if no results make sure you return something, either false or empty array depending on your needs.
    }
}
```

This way you can access the entire user object from your log results returned from the model like so, assuming your controller stays the same.

View

```
foreach($logs as $log) {
    echo $log->user->username;
}
```

or even...

```
foreach($logs as $log) {
    echo $log->user->email; //etc...
}
```

Comment: It brings more than needed information but it works Thanks :)

Comment: right, well, you can easily modify the model to get only what you need.  This was more proof of concept.